# Is there a way to force updates on Windows Desktop applications that are at the customer, using Azure Pipelines?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I have an WPF-application to which I regularly want to push software-updates to. For this I have used the tool *ApplifeUpdate* for years but is there a way to do this via Azure Pipelines which would be free for me because our company is a Microsoft Partner.

I know there are tools like *NetSparkleUpdater* and *AutoUpdater.NET* but want to explore the posibilites of doing it with a CI/CD tool like Pipelines.

Comment: Don´t think you can unless you want to install a self hosted agent on your customers PCs for running the pipeline on their PC. But you would end up DIY'ing the usability aspect of it anyway, it does not really solve anyhing meaningful. Imo just use CI to test / build the project and upload it somewhere the customer has access to and then you can use tools like AutoUpdater.NET to point to that location.

Comment: Local deployment groups do exist. Used for things like updating on prem IIS websites. Also requires you to run some code on every client to add it to a deployment group. Not clear how you´d do that with a desktop app as you probably don´t want to just kill and replace it (but that would be the easiest thing to do). As stated earlier you´d be DIY'ing the usability of it. Overall, I think it's weird to involve a CI solution that your client has to know about in order to do desktop app updates.

Comment: I've seen a couple of apps where the thing you initially run was just a very thin loader. That then looks at files on servers to get any newer version of dll that form the bulk of the app.  If you have a mature app that is likely to be quite a bit of work AND you have to get your new loader out to the clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically yes, but I think it would be highly unlikely your customer would agree to this, definitely fraught with peril, and overall inadvisable.

Azure Release Pipelines (like any devops tool) is intended for deploying to machines that the pipeline owner controls. It uses an agent installed on the target machines which effectively takes over the computer entirely and runs, well, anything you want it to run.

There are thus many problems with the idea of using pipelines with customer machines -

- You don't control them
- They might not always be on
- The customer is very unlikely to entrust you with the ability to take over their entire machine at any time.

This really is a square peg/round hole problem. *CAN* it be done? Sure. *SHOULD* it be done? Definitely not.

I recommend a professional installer/update framework. [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) (unaffiliated) is excellent and free and gives you a lot of control of the update process. Installers and update packages can be built (relatively) easily through CI/CD. Then you can use pipelines to post your update package on a public blob or wherever you like, and your customers' installed apps will check for updates and download them autopmatically. That would be a much more sensible use of Azure Pipelines in this context, rather than trying to push anything directly onto your customers' machines.